# How to arrange stack panels in a stack panel?

Tags: wpf

[image]

I am facing issue while arranging Stack panel as mention in the screenshots.
I am new to the WPF and I need to design a layout that look something like as mention in the image.

Comment: Why not using a Grid instead of the stack panel1? a grid allows you to do such an arrangement easily.

Comment: i agree Grid or DockPanel if you have a problem with grids

Comment: @ZSH, are you sure your comment came out quite right?

Comment: @user1194147, the `StackPanel` is *not* generally used to layout a whole window... they are better suited to lining up a number of controls in a section of the UI, *where the available space is not an issue*. Your life will be made *much* easier if you use a `Grid` because they are able to resize their contents, unlike the `StackPanel`.

Comment: @user1194147, I can't see a reason to push this task using StackPanel only. In case you are not aware/familiar with other type of panels : http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

Comment: "i Agree with @zahorak use grid and if not grid use a dockpanel" is what i meant, if it was unclear

Answer (score 2):

Zahorak is correct. There are a number of ways to create this layout, the best being a grid or a DockPanel. I prefer a DockPanel. A DockPanel allows you to position child controls around the edge of the DockPanel, filling the rest of the DockPanel (if you don't specify otherwise) with the last child control. For example, to achieve the result you are after, the xaml would be

```
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 3" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 5" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 4" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
```

A Grid layout requires a little more work.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 3" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 4" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Stack Panel 5" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Note that a missing Grid.Row or Grid.Column means a value of 0 (the first row or first column).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with pure stackpanels. You would have to set a width for the tall, narrow one (Stackpanel 3) in the second row

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="StackPanel1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StackPanel2">

    <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="StackPanel3">

        <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StackPanel4">

            <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StackPanel5">

            <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
```